# Is there a way to get long/lat for a given address in Google Maps with only PHP?

Tags: php, google-maps

I know this is possible in Javascript but I need to do it using only PHP, how can I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there's a [HTTP geocoding interface](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html) that you can call from any server language.

Answer (score 8):

And other way:

```
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Google Map API and PHP to get coordinates:

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='.$address.'&output=json&oe=utf8&sensor=false&key='.$api_key;
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$jsondata = json_decode($data,true);
if(is_array($jsondata )&& $jsondata ['Status']['code']==200){
  $lat = $jsondata ['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][0];
  $lon = $jsondata ['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

here is my class:

```
class GeoCoder {
public static function getLatLng($address){
    try{
        $address = urlencode($address);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false');

        $output= json_decode($geocode);

        $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
        if(is_numeric($lat) && is_numeric($lng)){
            return array("lat" => $lat, "lng" => $lng);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){            
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to get address from lat and long ([example usage](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false)).