# is it possible to find geolocation using zipcode using PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to find geolocation using zip code using PHP.

For example, if i am entering the zip code i need to find the name of that particular zipcode.

Is that possible? if yes kindly explain me how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get long/lat for a given address in Google Maps with only PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526057/is-there-a-way-to-get-long-lat-for-a-given-address-in-google-maps-with-only-php)

Answer (score 2):

See the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526057/is-there-a-way-to-get-long-lat-for-a-given-address-in-google-maps-with-only-php) on how to turn an address into coordinates using the Google Geocoding service.

A query in the format `[zipcode], United States`, e.g..

```
 72116, United States
```

should always work for you.

Try maps.google.com to simulate the request.

The XML returned from the Google Service will contain the official place name, as well as other information like county and state names etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through Javascript and PHP using Google's Map API - check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584835/problem-with-the-google-map-markers/3585075#3585075) for an example of how this is used.

I dont think it can be done solely through PHP however because you'd need to access an API's data and they normally (not always) do this through javascript.

You should check the [API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Geocoding API solely using PHP.. you don't even need an API Key anymore.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html

Answer (score 0):

So if understand this correctly, you want to know the City/State of the zip code you have entered?

Maybe you should look into the Access database here :
http://databases.about.com/od/access/a/zipcodedatabase.htm

And if you find it useful, just convert it into a MySQL table and use as you please.